# Fancybox close button not on top of youtube videos

Tags: youtube, fancybox, fancybox-2

The issue I'm running into with youtube videos is that the "close x" button that is at the top right is not on top of youtube videos.  For some reason its stuck underneath them.  I've tried it in all browsers to see if it was just a IE issue but it seems to be happening on all youtube videos.

I've also gone into the .css and changed the z-indext to so crazy high number to see if it would fix it but no luck, has anyone ran into this issue?  It seems to be isolated to youtube videos only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@complex857 is right, you need to change the `wmode` settings (to `opaque`) of the youtube video.

The best way to do it is:

1). Grab the latest release of fancybox (and helpers) from here https://github.com/fancyapps/fancyBox/tree/master/source

2). Beside your regular fancybox css and js files, add the fancybox-media helper js file like (check your own path):

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="fancybox2.0.6/helpers/jquery.fancybox-media.js"></script>
```

3). This new version allows you to pass specific parameters to youtube through  your custom script like :

```
   $(document).ready(function(){
    $(".fancybox").fancybox({
        // other API options here
        padding: 0, // optional
        // set helpers media
        helpers : {
         media : {}
        },
        // NEW youtube media settings
        youtube : {
         autoplay    : 0, // 1 = will enable autoplay
         wmode       : 'opaque'
        }
    }); // fancybox
   }); // ready
```

**NOTE** : this is for fancybox v2.0.6+

Comment: How do you download a single file from github?

Answer (score 2):

It's because the flash player that youtube uses wont respect z-index values of CSS with the default window mode (parameter name is wmode)

When embedding youtube iframe, add the **wmode=opaque** parameter to the URL (wmode=transparent will work too), so it will look like this:

```
<iframe width="420" height="315" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/<youtbue_id>?wmode=opaque" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Comment: Well I'm not embedding the video.  I'm just grabbing the youtube URL to use inside of fancybox with the media helper.